# Salesforce IDP for external users

Tags: community, identity

Is it required to procure community cloud license to use Salesforce IDP for external users (B2C Customers).

Also, when those customers logs-in to a website using Salesforce as an IDP, they get created on Salesforce as users. Does this utilize the limit of users one have on the Salesforce license?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Customer Community License is for Business-to-consumer communities with large numbers of external users.

This decision tree will help you to choose correct license type.

[image: License type]

For more information, refer [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5)

You can do small poc on the same and verify the license count upon navigating `Company Information` page, after creating user.